# How to programmatically compute this summation

Tags: matlab, nested-loops

[image]

I want to compute the above summation, for a given 'x'. The summation is to be carried out over a block of lengths specified by an array , for example `block_length = [5 4 3]`. The summation is carried as follows: from -5 to 5 across one dimension, -4 to 4 in the second dimension and -3 to 3 in the last dimension.

The pseudo code will be something like this:

```
sum = 0;
for i = -5:5
for j = -4:4
for k = -3:3

      vec = [i j k];

      tv = vec * vec';

      sum = sum + 1/(1+tv)*cos(2*pi*x*vec'));

end
end
end
```

The problem is that I want to find the sum when the number of dimensions are not known ahead of time, using some kind of variable nested loops hopefully. Matlab uses `combvec`, but it returns all possible combinations of vectors, which is not required as we only compute the sum. When there are many dimensions, `combvec` returning all combinations is not feasible memory wise.

Appreciate any ideas towards solutions.

PS: I want to do this at high number of dimensions, for example 650, as in machine learning.

Comment: _dimensions are arbitrary_: Do you mean that the _number_ of dimensions is arbitrary, or that the _size_ along each dimension is arbitrary? _at high dimensions like 650_: Do you mean you may have up to 650 dimensions? If so, even having only two values per dimension would produce an unmanageably large number of values

Comment: sum = sum + 1/(1+tv)*cos(2*pi*x*vec')) is incorrect: you should remove the last closed parenthesis.

Comment: is x a scalar or a vector? The notation would suggest it's a vector: if that's the case, what are its dimensions? I am assuming the product between l and x should produce a scalar... Please, provide a minimal working example with a sample input and the expected output.

Comment: X is a vector of dimensions the same as summation. For example '3' in the case of example shown. Number of dimensions are arbitrary means, I mean programatically, the number of dimensions is not known while writing the code, meaning, code wshould be able to handle any number of dimensions. The dimensions being very high is not a problem as at the end, memorywise, we just need to compute a single number. (the sum).

Comment: @picchiolu : x = [0.1 0.2 0.3], l = [1 2 3]. l*x = 0.1+0.4+0.9 = 1.4.

Comment: @RajeshD With 650 dimensions, having just 2 values per dimension means that you need to add `2^650` values. Even if each individual addition takes only 1 picosecond, the sum would take longer than the current age of the universe

Comment: @LuisMendo indeed, the code I proposed in my answer, for the following trivial case (relatively to the max dimension suggested by the OP): ```tic; in = 0.1 * ones(1, 16); sum = fun(in, ones(size(in))), toc```, runs in more than 12 seconds.

Comment: @RajeshD, would you please share more information about the equation you posted in your question? If it's related to machine learning, there might be libraries implementing it: maybe there's even some source code available you can look into.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/345551-function-with-varying-number-of-for-loops I came up with the following code (I haven't tested it for very large number of indices!):

```
function sum = fun(x, block_length)

sum = 0;
n = numel(block_length);   % Number of loops
vec = -ones(1, n) .* block_length;   % Index vector

ready = false;
while ~ready
    
    tv = vec * vec';
    
    sum = sum + 1/(1+tv)*cos(2*pi*x*vec');
    
    % Update the index vector:
    ready = true;    % Assume that the WHILE loop is ready
    for k = 1:n
        vec(k) = vec(k) + 1;
        if vec(k) <= block_length(k)
            ready = false;
            break;    % v(k) increased successfully, leave "for k" loop
        end
        vec(k) = -1 * block_length(k);    % v(k) reached the limit, reset it
    end
end
end
```

where `x` and `block_length` should be both 1-x-n vectors.

The idea is that, instead of using explicitly nested loops, we use a vector of indices.

How good/efficient is this when tackling the suggested use case where `block_length` can have 650 elements? Not much! Here's a "quick" test using merely 16 dimensions and a [-1, 1] range for the indices:

```
N = 16; tic; in = 0.1 * ones(1, N); sum = fun(in, ones(size(in))), toc;
```

which yields an elapsed time of 12.7 seconds on my laptop.